# How to Change style order in Antd and LESS?

Tags: reactjs, less, antd, craco

I'm using `antd`, `craco` with less-module.

And I created module.less file for `antd` customization test.

Result is image below.

[image]

I want to change css style order like image above.

And this is my `craco.config.js`.

```js
const CracoLessPlugin = require('craco-less');

const modifyVars = {
  '@primary-color': '#253798',
};

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
      options: {
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          lessOptions: {
            modifyVars: modifyVars,
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      plugin: CracoLessPlugin,
      options: {
        modifyLessRule: function (lessRule, _context) {
          lessRule.test = /\.module\.(less)$/;
          lessRule.use = [
            {
              loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
            },
            {
              loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
              options: {
                modules: true,
                // localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
            {
              loader: require.resolve('less-loader'),
              options: {
                lessOptions: {
                  modifyVars: modifyVars,
                  javascriptEnabled: true,
                },
              },
            },
          ];
          lessRule.exclude = /node_modules/;
          return lessRule;
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

I have 3 questions.

1. How to Change style order in Antd and less module?
2. How to override Antd css attributes with less module?
3. Is there any other good way to customize Antd?

(I don't want to use tags that wrap Andt components)

Comment: Having the same issue and cant find a way of how to solve this. Have you managed to solve this?